# How to edit docker mysql image and increase connection limit

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am new docker concepts. I have mysql image which is already build. I want to increase mysql connection limit to 10000 within configuration file. I researching a lot about this, but I didn't found any clue on this. How can I get mysql configuration file and change settings?

Comment: command: --max_connections=10000

Comment: do you mean running a command will increase connection limit permanently?

Comment: mybe you can share your image dockerfile or compose so we can help you

Comment: how can we get that physical image file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can run the container like this:

```
docker run -d -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test" mysql --max_connections=10000
```

or make your own `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql
CMD [ "--max_connections=10000" ]
```

then build it:

```
docker build -t my_mysql .
```

and run it:

```
docker run -d -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test" my_mysql
```

Comment: okay but running a command will set same setting permanently?

Comment: okay since I am running this commands using linux server, how can I create docker file over there and run the same? please suggest

Comment: what do you mean ? just follow what in the answer

Comment: how do you check it ?

Comment: @LinPy yes the syntax `"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test"` was correct too, sorry. my mistake

Comment: running perfectly by mentioning name of the container as                             
   `docker run --name mysql1 -d -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test" mysql --max_connections=10000`

Answer (score 3):

Create Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql
COPY custom.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
```

Create custom configuration file `custom.cnf` in the same folder where Dockerfile is with contents:

```
[mysqld]
max_connections = 1024
```

Rebuild the image `docker build -t my_mysql .` in the same folder where Dockerfile is

Run the container:

`docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test --name=my_mysql my_mysql`

Check if configuration changed:

```
docker exec -i my_mysql mysql -uroot -ptest -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';"
```

You should see:

```
Variable_name   Value
max_connections 1024
```